# Are we too ferocious?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, behavior

About this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59754747/how-to-compare-time-in-php ([question screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAqxG.png))

Yesterday a question has been asked by what seemed to be a new contributor. Granted the question was not of the highest standard, but it was quickly closed as a duplicate of what seemed to be an unrelated topic. We have asked for clarifications in the comments and OP has been helpful and confirmed the exact requirement they had. Albeit uncommon requirement and most likely an XY problem (it could be solved in a different way), the question which OP had at the time could easily be answered.

Soon after the last comment was posted the user disappeared, which leads me to believe that they deleted their own account in rage over our behaviour. Were we being unpleasant towards OP even though they were clear and cooperative?

[image: comments screenshot]

Comment: The user doesn't seem to be enraged from the comments. I can't see the deleted question, but sometimes users delete questions or accounts because they don't want coworkers/tutors etc to find it. Could be one reason.

Comment: It seems too much like a coincidence. Last comment was posted and the account got deleted few minutes later.

Comment: Could be a coincidence or OP realizing they were wrong. It's just speculation at this point. As for being too ferocious: this is a pretty tame example, I have seen far worse. Yes, we are sometimes too ferocious, esp in comments, but I wouldn't say it applies to this example.

Comment: I thought there was a 24 hour delay for self-deletion of account?

Comment: @ivarni IIRC you can delete your account immediately if you posted or voted just once. (Found it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account: "If you have never posted or voted more than once on your profile, it will be _immediately_ deleted.")

Comment: That looks like a throw away account, not like a frustrated user rage quitting. But of course, we'll never know. I see nothing wrong with the comments or closure.

Comment: @ModusTollens I've always read that as *"never (posted or (voted more than once))"*, not *"never ((posted or voted) more than once)"*.

Comment: @NickA our understanding of boolean logic as programmers is skewing our understanding of English

Answer (score 11):

I see two comments that do not ask for or offer clarification:

- > Sometimes I wonder if some questions are traps to lure you into breaking the *Code of Conduct*...
- > *because it is the time when I backup my server the users should not be able to login..* I knew that question was a XY-problem

These comments are not offensive per se, but they are not nice nor helpful. They should not have been posted and not have been upvoted, but once they were there they should have been flagged and removed instead.

If those two comments, and the duplicate vote (which definitely is correct), and the downvotes chased the OP away, then that's their loss, because this question is not an addition to the site, as it has been asked and answered plenty of times before. In all of its variations, the linked duplicate is not the only one that deals with this subject.

The user should have showed more effort, then they wouldn't have been downvoted.

So no, I don't think "we" are too "ferocious", but there's still plenty of users who think they're funny or edgy when they aren't.

Comment: And if the mis-matches (which aren't apparent in the code shown here) *were* the problem this should have been a comment and VTC as "typo/no repro". So lots of things odd about this... I've flagged it for Mod attention with explanation to hopefully get rid of it.

Comment: Nice answer. To clarify why I think the duplicate is not 100% fit: OP asked how to compare hours and minutes, not dates or timestamps. While the duplicate could still be useful it is not an exact duplicate. I am not keen on closing questions as duplicates if it is not obvious how they are helpful. For OP my answer in the comments should explain how to compare the hours and minutes against a string.

Comment: @CindyMeister Yeah - there's definitely been some fishy editing been done on both Q and A. I'm sorely tempted to rollback the Q to Rev. 1 but, as you've mod-flagged it, probably best to stay away.

Comment: The CoC comment, while funny, is not helpful and could be interpreted as slightly non-nice to OP. I don't see how the XY problem comment is _not nice_, and might be slightly helpful if OP knows what "XY problem" means (or googles it and learns the meaning). It could easily be made helpful by adding "ask a new question about backing up your data instead".

Comment: @l4mpi it is not constructive, it is commentary aimed at nobody in particular.

Comment: @CodeCaster yeah, it's not the most constructive thing in the world, but your answer states it's _not nice_. I don't see how.

Comment: @l4mpi From the question askers perspective that comment is similar to asking someone a question in person and they give their buddy on the side a little nudge and whisper "hey, check out this fool, I knew it was gonna be that kind of problem."